# Variable to return or return directly?

Tags: c, function, return

I'm learning to program and sometimes I find that using a variable to return makes my code more readable.

I was wondering if these functions perform the same operations and are equally efficient.

**CASE 1:**

```
int Foo1()
{
    int x = 5 + 6 + 7;      // Return variable
    return x;
}

int Foo2(int y)
{
    return 5 + 6 + 7;
}
```

In this case I think that the initialization and sum occur at compile time so there's no difference between them.

**CASE 2:**

```
int Foo1(int y)
{
    int x = y + 6 + 7;      // Return variable
    return x;
}

int Foo2(int y)
{
    return y + 6 + 7;
}
```

But, what happen in this case? It seems that the initialization occur at execution time and it has to perform it.

Is returning the value directly faster than initialize a variable and then returning it? Should I always try to return values directly instead using a variable to return?

Comment: The compiler will compile them down to the same code in many cases. Worry about readability instead of performance in a case like this though.

Comment: "Is returning the value directly faster ...." --> this is premature optimization.  Focus on larger issues and let the compiler handle the small stuff.

Comment: @chux: They are not optimizing a program, so this is not premature. They are asking about principles, to inform their thinking and to be used later, not to optimize a current program.

Comment: One advantage of the split operation is that you can put a debugger breakpoint on the return statement and print the value that will be returned.  If the expression is part of the return, you can't do that, so finding the actual return value is harder.  This assumes you don't do too much optimization while debugging.  When you are optimizing, there won't be much if any difference — the compiler will effectively rewrite to a direct return, so there's no penalty.

Comment: Best comment goes to Jonathan Leffler. Huge thing is that you can put a debugger breakpoint on the return. Especially in cases where you have many functions in the call stack having the same thing doing return something; return something; until maybe 5-7 functions down till you can see the value... more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily try this yourself.
You can get the assembly from your compiler

Without optimization:
(`gcc -S -O0 -o src.S src.c`)

```
    .file   "so_temp.c"
    .text
    .globl  case1Foo1
    .type   case1Foo1, @function
case1Foo1:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $18, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   case1Foo1, .-case1Foo1
    .globl  case1Foo2
    .type   case1Foo2, @function
case1Foo2:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $18, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   case1Foo2, .-case1Foo2
    .globl  case2Foo1
    .type   case2Foo1, @function
case2Foo1:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
    movl    -20(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $13, %eax
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2:
    .size   case2Foo1, .-case2Foo1
    .globl  case2Foo2
    .type   case2Foo2, @function
case2Foo2:
.LFB3:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    addl    $13, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE3:
    .size   case2Foo2, .-case2Foo2
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Ther you can see, that the foo2 versions have a few instructions less than the foo1 versions of the functions.

With optimization turned to O3:
(`gcc -S -O3 -o src.S src.c`)

```
    .file   "so_temp.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  case1Foo1
    .type   case1Foo1, @function
case1Foo1:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $18, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   case1Foo1, .-case1Foo1
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  case1Foo2
    .type   case1Foo2, @function
case1Foo2:
.LFB5:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $18, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE5:
    .size   case1Foo2, .-case1Foo2
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  case2Foo1
    .type   case2Foo1, @function
case2Foo1:
.LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    leal    13(%rdi), %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2:
    .size   case2Foo1, .-case2Foo1
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  case2Foo2
    .type   case2Foo2, @function
case2Foo2:
.LFB7:
    .cfi_startproc
    leal    13(%rdi), %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE7:
    .size   case2Foo2, .-case2Foo2
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

both versions are exactly the same.

Still I don't think that this is something you should optimize yourself.
In this case readable code should be preferred, especially as code normally isn't compiled with optimizations turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Case 2 is more efficient, but is often not needed as the compiler is extremely likely to optimize case 1 into case 2.

Go for readability if it doesn't hurt performance (as in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Any compiler of at least modest quality will, at even low levels of optimization (such as GCC’s `-O1`), [compile these to the same code](https://godbolt.org/z/XdGfAf). For the most part, any correct optimization you can easily see will be performed by a good compiler.

The C standard does not require compilers to mindlessly compile code into instructions that perform the exact steps in the C source code. It only requires compilers to produce code that has the same effects. Those effects are defined in terms of *observable behavior*, which includes the output of the program, interactions with the user, and access to volatile objects (special objects you will learn about later). Compilers will eliminate things like intermediate variables as long as they can do so without changing the observable behavior.